# Testing DialogFragment in ActivityUnitTestCase

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, android-dialogfragment, testcase

I am using an ActivityUnitTestCase to test behavior of an Activity. When a method on the activity is called, a DialogFragment should be displayed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365561/testing-dialog-in-androids-activityunittestcase) gives the impression that this particular behavior cannot be tested with this type of TestCase.

The problem with alternatively using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is that I cannot control the dependency injection used when the Activity is created.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ((App) getApplication()).inject(this);
  ...
}
```

For dependency injection, I am using Dagger. The Application subclass `App` holds a reference to an object graph and injects references into this Activity upon `onCreate` being called. In an ActivityUnitTestCase, I can provide a mock App with its own object graph for injecting objects against which I can make assertions. This is not possible in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, as far as I know.

The relevant test method is below:

```
public void testMyMethod_displaysDialogFragment() {
  startActivity(new Intent(), null, null);
  currentActivity.myMethod();
  getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync(); // irrelevant
  MyDialogFragment fragment = (MyDialogFragment) currentActivity
    .getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyDialogFragment");
  assertNotNull("should display the dialog", fragment); // fails
}
```

The only solution I can determine would be to use a factory or Dagger Provider to inject and test against. It would allow me to use ActivityUnitTestCase, but would *greatly* complicate the app structure. For something as simple as "call this method when this button is clicked" behavior, I would very much like to avoid that.

Does anyone have any ideas about resolving these limitations?